# SSRS won't read my SQL query parameters

Tags: reporting-services, spatial-data

I'm trying to plot data to a shapefile in SSRS. I linked my SQL Server successfully and selected my Stored Procedure, but when I go to set my Spatial and Analytical Dataset Fields SSRS tells my

> Procedure or function 'uspStoredProcedure' expects parameter '@eventId', which was not supplied.

I don't understand because I explicitly entered `eventId` on the page directly before this, ran the query and everything came up just as expected.

Comment: Make sure `@eventId` is exactly the same in you SP as you parameter name, they are case sensitive. If this doesn't help you'll have to edit your question and post more details. How are you passing he parameter to the SP? what type of value does your SP expect? What are you parameter properties? etc...

Comment: In the GUI I'm walking through the New Map Wizard. I load in my shapefile, choose Color Analytical for Map Visualization, add my data source from an existing database, then select the Stored Procedure from the cascading menu on the next page. This page has 2 boxes; Selected Fields and Function Parameters. This is where I type in my parameter values to run the query. The next screen is "Create a relationship between spatial and analytical data" and its where I'm getting the "Procedure/Function ... expects parameter `@eventId` which was not supplied"